# Get youtube video information faster

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube

Right now I am getting the information of a youtube video by using the Data API Protocol
Visiting this url displays the information I need, but its much too slow for doing a dozen queries. It takes around 10 seconds to get 24 videos.

Is there a way to send multiple queries in 1 request or another method for 
getting the information faster? Right now I am only using this to get the ratings.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[video id]
```

edit: at this moment I am getting it via php with get_file_contents().
Is there a faster page downloading function than that?

Comment: Why are you using an encrypted protocol? That's slowing it down significantly

Comment: Simple solution: Do multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: @ alienwebguy It goes the exact same speed if I dont use it secure. @Chronial how can I do that with php?

Comment: @Drake curl has such a feature, see [`curl_multi_init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) and the other curl_multi functions.

Comment: Are you opening up a new curl connection for each request? how are you fetching these feeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of getting downvoted: I would just send the whole page without the ratings and use ajax / jquery to add the ratings when the page is completely loaded. The speed will then depend on the visitor's internet connection and browser (for the number of simultaneous requests).

By the way, I know this is not an optimal solution; it is based on the fact that the two other solutions were rejected...

Comment: I am already doing that as an alternative since all these other users failed to come up with a single working solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get multiple URLs in a single request unless it is functionality specified by the API or feed you are pulling from.  If youtube's API doesn't allow you to pull in multiple items in a single request then for performance you should look into preloading and caching these URLS.

If you know before hand which items you need ratings for then set up a cronjob to pull them in before hand and then cache them in some sort of persistent database.

Comment: Its not something I can cache, its going to get the data from what every page the user is currently on. So caching thousands of video ratings that update every minute is not an option.

Comment: Ah I see.  In that case it might make sense to load the page and then have some kind of loading icon in place of the ratings while you pull them in on the front end.

Comment: I´m curious, how is this answer `not useful`?

Answer (score 2):

Make all your curl calls at once:

Say you have 10 video ID's:

```
kcvq0RcBkOE
OYpwAtnywTk
EvHwh9O9Tsg
```

... And so on

Concatenate them with curly braces in the url like such:

```
curl http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{kcvq0RcBkOE,OYpwAtnywTk,EvHwh9O9Tsg}
```